# Pointer in class name before scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, pointers

I am moving from c to c++ and came across scoperesolution page info here and was quite helpful
[What does "ClassName ClassName::FunctionName" mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660218/what-does-classname-classnamefunctionname-mean-in-c)

But I also came across the following code which I am planning to learn and it has a pointer before class name, so my question is in what circumstance would one use the pointer.

```
const char *TObject::ClassName() const
{
   // Returns name of class to which the object belongs.
   return IsA()->GetName();
}
```

Comment: It is common to write this as `const char* TObject::ClassName() const` to emphasize that the `*` belongs to the return type, and that it doesn't mean a function pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regular definition of a member function outside of its class. The asterisk has no special meaning in this context.

First, recall how you define a function in C that returns a pointer:

```
const char *Foo() {
   return something;
}
```

The declaration that you see has the same structure, except for two elements:

- Full name of the function uses a scope resolution operator, and
- There is a `const` after the function.

What scope resolution means is that `ClassName` is a member-function belonging to class `TObject`, and the `const` at the end means that the code of the member-function does not alter member variables of its class.